# R pass argument when sourcing another file under foreach

Tags: r, windows, parallel-foreach

I wrote a program `to_source.R` which leaves some configuration parameters out. Now I want to run for different parameters in parallel. For example,

In `to_source.R`

```
cat(paste0(config, ' is finished')
```

and in `main.R`

```
config = 1
source("to_source.R")
```

This works. But running in parallel (with foreach/doParallel in windows)

In `main_para.R`

```
parallel_cluster = parallel::makeCluster(5)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(parallel_cluster)

configs = 6:10
foreach(config = configs, .combine = rbind, .packages = c("data.table", "foreach")) %dopar% {
  source("to_source.R")
}

parallel::stopCluster(parallel_cluster)
```

This fails because **Error in { : task 1 failed - object 'config' not found**

This is very close to the question [How to pass command-line arguments when source() an R file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14525580/1568919), but the answer there does not work under `foreach`